# Не работает блок "поделиться" от Яндекс

Tags: ya-share2

Этим кодом подключил блок *поделиться* в трёх соц. сетях.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki"></div>
```

Кнопки появились, но делятся этой ссылкой `harsupesa.wix.com.usrfiles.com` при нажатии на которую открывается пустая страничка с блоком *поделиться* в левом верхнем углу.

Может что-то надо прописать в коде?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Из [документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/add-docpage/#attributes) блока "Поделиться":

> По умолчанию указывается URL страницы, на которой размещен блок.

Вы можете указать произвольный URL, указав его в data-атрибуте:

```
<div class="ya-share2"
     data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki"
     data-url="https://ya.ru"></div>
```

Также стоит учитывать, что некоторые социальные сети (например, Facebook) игнорируют этот параметр. Чтобы передать им необходимую информацию, следует использовать специальную разметку.

Подробнее об это можно прочитать в статье ["Как устроен мир семантической микроразметки"](https://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/211638/).